# How Does Low Volume Affect (esp. live.com) Email Deliverability?

Tags: email, smtp, spam

I've been sending emails for years with out any serious reputational shocks, but with low IP volumes (no bulk mail or automated transactional email), even with multiple Domain names.

My Gmail deliverability is fair, however my hotmail/outlook.com/live.com and mail.com deliverability is poor, invariably being accepted, then confined to the Spam folder.

My sender host's rDNS is appropriately set, I'm a member of the JMRP and SNDS programs, send mail which receives a "PASS" for both SPF and DKIM and I have a SenderScore of 100...

Short of paying to register for Return Path Certified (which would presumably fail because of the multiple domain names) can anyone offer any advice as to where one might look for clues as to what's holding me back?

Comment: Maybe someone is spamming your domain (have you received a lot of unrecognized delivery failure notice)?

Comment: No, none at all - my situation is very stable and tragically unspecific -- I ought to add that I've been using DMARC for a little while now to keep an eye on just that - and there are perhaps 2 or three attempts a day, tops.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a free 3rd party ESP, as they take extra steps to ensure abuse handled and monitored they have a higher reputation with receivers.

Personally I like [MandrillApp](http://www.mandrillapp.com) which you could easily use for free, there are many others, be sure to avoid ESP's that use purchased [Lists](https://wordtothewise.com/2015/05/purchased-lists-and-esps/), and [Word to the Wise](https://wordtothewise.com/category/delivery-improvement/) has some other great suggestions as well!